# FILETIME to __int64

Tags: c++, int64

What is the proper way to convert a `FILETIME` structure into `__int64`? Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 17):

I don't think you're suppose to: "Do not cast a pointer to a `FILETIME` structure to either a `ULARGE_INTEGER*` or `__int64*` value because it can cause alignment faults on 64-bit Windows."

[Source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28VS.85%29.aspx)

If you really wanted it would be something like:

```
__int64 to_int64(FILETIME ft)
{
    return static_cast<__int64>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32 | ft.dwLowDateTime;
}

FILETIME ft = // ...
__int64 t = to_int64(ft);
```

But something like:

```
FILETIME ft = // ...
__int64 t = *reinterpet_cast<__int64*>(&ft);
```

Is bad.

Comment: How about memcpy(<__int64>, &FILETIME, 8); ? Is it safe?

Comment: I would find `memcpy` harder to understand, but I'm sure it would work. The compiler can probably optimize shift and or better.

Comment: Indeed, it was harder to understand, but it has worked so far :) Thanks

Comment: If one wants to convert it to UNIX time, one has to use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370920/convert-current-time-from-windows-to-unix-timestamp-in-c-or-c.

Answer (score 16):

There is no need to revert to arcane constructs using bitwise OR's. The Windows API has got everything you need to do this.

```
unsigned __int64    convert( const FILETIME & ac_FileTime )
{
  ULARGE_INTEGER    lv_Large ;

  lv_Large.LowPart  = ac_FileTime.dwLowDateTime   ;
  lv_Large.HighPart = ac_FileTime.dwHighDateTime  ;

  return lv_Large.QuadPart ;
}
```

Or if you want to go to __int64 directly.

```
__int64 convert_to_int64( const FILETIME & ac_FileTime )
{
  return static_cast< __int64 > ( convert( ac_FileTime ) ) ;
}
```

Comment: These days (since C++11) it can simply be written as `ULARGEINTEGER{ ft.dwLowDateTime, ft.dwHighDateTime }.QuadPart`. Arguably not more readable however you don't need any additional function/macro.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
(__int64(filetime.dwHighDateTime)<<32) | __int64(filetime.dwLowDateTime)
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you could just pass in an __int64 casted to a filetime as follows *(FILETIME*)&int64Val.  This will work fine under Visual C++.

ie

```
__int64 createTime = 0;
__int64 accessTime = 0;
__int64 writeTime = 0;
GetFileTime( hFile, *(FILETIME*)&createTime, *(FILETIME*)&accessTime, *(FILETIME*)&writeTime );
```

Comment: "Do not cast a pointer to a FILETIME structure to either a ULARGE_INTEGER* or __int64* value because it can cause alignment faults on 64-bit Windows." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime

Comment: @MrTux: In the link it says that you mustn't cast FROM a FILETIME structure.   The 2 meanings are very different.  Basically a FILETIME might be on a 4 byte alignment (or maybe even a 2) and so casting to an __int64 will cause alignment issues as an __int64 is necessarily 8 byte aligned.  However in the function above I pass in an 8 byte aligned __int64 and windows writes into it.  It doesn't change the address of the pointer just because its an __int64.  That would break all kinds of things.

Comment: Really like this answer, because it makes perfect sense in the light of the *real* meaning of the documentation advise; and the [description by Raimond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=38053). Thanks tor intelligent advise!

Answer (score 1):

you can try the code follow. the code is from chromium project

```
template <class Dest, class Source>
inline Dest bit_cast(const Source& source) {
    Dest dest;
    memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof(dest));
    return dest;
}

//FILETIME to __int64

__int64 FileTimeToMicroseconds(const FILETIME& ft) {
    return bit_cast<__int64, FILETIME>(ft) / 10;
}

void MicrosecondsToFileTime(__int64 us, FILETIME* ft) {
    *ft = bit_cast<FILETIME, __int64>(us * 10);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __int64 nTmpUint64 = 13060762249644841;

    time_t unixtime;
    FILETIME nTmpFileTm;
    MicrosecondsToFileTime(nTmpUint64,&nTmpFileTm);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, googled for it, and came here. But I also found a useful Microsoft support page at
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/188768/info-working-with-the-filetime-structure

It says:

---

**Performing Arithmetic with File Times**

It is often necessary to perform a simple arithmetic on file times. For example, you might need to know when a file is 30 days old. To perform an arithmetic on a file time, you need to convert the FILETIME to a quadword (a 64-bit integer), perform the arithmetic, and then convert the result back to a FILETIME.

Assuming ft is a FILETIME structure containing the creation time of a file, the following sample code adds 30 days to the time:

```
   ULONGLONG qwResult;

   // Copy the time into a quadword.
   qwResult = (((ULONGLONG) ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;

   // Add 30 days.
   qwResult += 30 * _DAY;

   // Copy the result back into the FILETIME structure.
   ft.dwLowDateTime  = (DWORD) (qwResult & 0xFFFFFFFF );
   ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD) (qwResult >> 32 );
```

---

Edit: I realise this merely confirms some of the other answers, but I thought it was worth adding for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

#### Three ways that have best performance (one assembler instruction). Tested only in Visual C++ 2022 x64.

```cpp
auto u = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(ft)
```

The best way.

```cpp
auto u = *reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t _UNALIGNED*>(&ft)
```

Disadvantage: `_UNALIGNED` macro (and `__unaligned` modifier) is non-standard. But almost every compiler has this modifier in some form.

```cpp
memcpy(&u, &ft, sizeof(u))
```

Disadvantage: this code will be well optimized only if you turn on “Enable Intrinsic Functions” C++ compiler option.

#### Other answers have some overheads.

```cpp
(static_cast<std::uint64_t>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) | ft.dwLowDateTime
```

Generates bitwise operations.

```cpp
ULARGE_INTEGER{ft.dwLowDateTime, ft.dwHighDateTime}.QuadPart
```

Generates two 32-bit operations instead of one 64-bit one.

Comment: what the compiler does with the _unaligned cast will vary between platforms; don't recommend it. My preferred solution is to actually just use uint64_t for all FILETIME variables and reinterpret_cast as needed for the interfaces (which is perfectly safe as uint64_t has the required 8 byte alignment, but FILETIME only has 4 byte alignment). I also do this for LARGE_INTEGER to avoid having to monkey with QuadPart