# Convert current time from windows to unix timestamp in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix, time

First off, I know that this question was asked quite some times (although it seems that 90% are about converting Unix ts -> Windows).
Secondly, I would add a comment to another accepted question where my problem would fit in instead of adding another one but I don't have enough reputation.

I saw the accepted solution in [Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux) but am stuck at what I should pass to the function **WindowsTickToUnixSeconds**. Judging by the parameter name *windowsTicks* I tried [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but saw shortly after that this returns the ms **since the system started** but I need any reasonable count since the **start of the Windows time** (which seems to was in 1601?).

I saw that windows has a function for retrieving this time: [GetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I cannot pass the resulting struct to the proposed function in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux) as it is not a long long value.

Can't someone please just give a full working example for C or C++ without omitting such mad-driving details?

Comment: [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167296) at least contains the opposite conversion.

Comment: Give it a Filetime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe my question was phrased badly: All I wanted was to get the current time on a windows machine as a unix timestamp.
I now figured it out myself (C language, Code::Blocks 12.11, Windows 7 64 bit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    time_t ltime;
    time(&ltime);
    printf("Current local time as unix timestamp: %li\n", ltime);

    struct tm* timeinfo = gmtime(&ltime); /* Convert to UTC */
    ltime = mktime(timeinfo); /* Store as unix timestamp */
    printf("Current UTC time as unix timestamp: %li\n", ltime);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Current local time as unix timestamp: 1386334692
Current UTC time as unix timestamp: 1386331092
```

Comment: on my win10  time(&ltime) returns GMT time, not local.  and I'm not in GMT timezone.

Answer (score 15):

And for people on Windows:

```
Int64 GetSystemTimeAsUnixTime()
{
   //Get the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 12:00am UTC
   //Code released into public domain; no attribution required.

   const Int64 UNIX_TIME_START = 0x019DB1DED53E8000; //January 1, 1970 (start of Unix epoch) in "ticks"
   const Int64 TICKS_PER_SECOND = 10000000; //a tick is 100ns

   FILETIME ft;
   GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(out ft); //returns ticks in UTC

   //Copy the low and high parts of FILETIME into a LARGE_INTEGER
   //This is so we can access the full 64-bits as an Int64 without causing an alignment fault
   LARGE_INTEGER li;
   li.LowPart  = ft.dwLowDateTime;
   li.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
 
   //Convert ticks since 1/1/1970 into seconds
   return (li.QuadPart - UNIX_TIME_START) / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
}
```

The name of the function matches the naming scheme used by other Windows functions. The Windows **System Time** is *by definition* UTC.

| Function | Return type | Resolution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GetSystemTimeAsFileTime | FILETIME struct | 0.0000001 s |
| GetSystemTime | SYSTEMTIME struct | 0.001 s |
| GetSystemTimeAsUnixTime | Int64 | 1 s |

Comment: Great solution! However, why int64 when it fits into an int? 2,147,483,647 – The End of Time [Unix] = int max length 2,147,483,647.

Comment: @Mecanik [We use an Int64 because we're not terrible programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Answer (score 1):

With the [`SYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure set by [`GetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's easy to create a a `struct tm` (see [`asctime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kys1801b.aspx) for a reference of the structure) and convert it to a "UNIX time stamp" using the [`mktime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1y53h2a.aspx) function.